# Database error handling in entity framework

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, entity-framework, error-handling

I wrote stored procedure witch sometimes **RAISERROR()**.
I execute it through the entity framework like:

```
using( MyModelEntities conn = new MyModelEntities() ) {
    conn.MyStoredProcedure(input_p, output_p);
}
```

Stored procedure:

```
create procedure dbo.MyStoredProcedure(
    @input   nvarchar(255),
    @output int out
)
as
begin
    ...
        RAISERROR (N'My Exception....', 10, 1);
    ...
end
go
```

Is there any opportunity to get information about error?

Answer (score 4):

In sql server exception level 1 to 10 are informational and does not raise error back to your application.

change Level in between 11 to 16 to raise error from the SP.

Answer (score 2):

Can this just be put into a try/catch with the exception displayed?  Or maybe you could try going into debug mode?

Comment: Btw. I was too fast... RAISERROR is not returning exception. Only Sql Server Erorrs... So how can I handle my Custom errors?

Comment: Are you catching an instance of SqlException in your Try/Catch block, and using its Messsage or Errors properties?: (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlexception.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I handle this:

```
create procedure dbo.MyStoredProcedure(
    @input   nvarchar(255),
    @output  text out
)
as
begin
    ...
      SELECT @message = convert(varchar, getdate(), 108) + ': My Exception....'
      SET @output = CAST(@message AS text) -- send message to c#/.net
      RAISERROR(@message,0,1) WITH NOWAIT  -- send message to SQL Server Management Studio
    ...
end
go
```

Then on the C#/EF side:

```
public string CallMyStoredProcedure(string input)
{
    var outputParameter = new ObjectParameter("output", typeof(string));
    EntityContext.MyStoredProcedure(input, outputParameter);
    return (string)outputParameter.Value;
}
```